# Update state from other Component to Main Component

Tags: reactjs, components, state, react-props

I created a component/file in my React-Project, so that I can better organize it.
I have exported a Login-Component `<SignInSide></SignInSide>` and imported it in my main file:

Main-File:

```
export default class Login extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: ""
    };
  }

  onChangeUsername(e) {
    this.setState({
      username: e.target.value
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
        <SignInSide></SignInSide>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my very basic Login-Component. As I already said, I just want to call `this.onChangeUsernam` when I imported this as `<SignInSide></SignInSide>` but i dont know what I have to write inside the onClick-Argument inside of the Login-Component to get/update the state from the Main-File.

Login-Component

```
export default function SignInSide(props) {

  return (
          <form className={classes.form}>
            <TextField/>
            <Button>
              Login
            </Button>
          </form>
  );
}
```

I am very thankful for helping. Can you give me a short and easy to understand example, so that I  can add this by myself to my project? I only have to understand, what i have to do.

Comment: I believe that what you need is to update `state` with `TextField` when click on the button ?

Comment: @KavinduVIndika Yes, but I dont know how to do, because this are two seperate files, and the state part is in the other file! Can you helpe me please???

Comment: Yes sure @Fynn, let me create a proper answer...happy coding

Answer (score 0):

To update the `Login` component's state, you need to pass props from parent component to child component (passing props from `Login` to `SignInSide` component).

Therefore, you need to pass `onChangeUsername` method as a prop to the `<SignInSide/>` component. Inside `SignInSide` component, you need to manage a local state to keep the text input that you entered. It only needs to be used when you're submitting the `data` which trigger the onClick function `onChangeUsername` which has been passed from parent component.

**Main-File**:

```
import { Component } from "react";
import SignInSide from "./SignInSide";

export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onChangeUsername = this.onChangeUsername.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      username: "",
    };
  }

  onChangeUsername(data) {
    this.setState({
      username: data,
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log("username updated: ", this.state.username);
    return <SignInSide onChangeUsername={this.onChangeUsername} />;
  }
}
```

**SignInSide Component**:

```
import { useState } from "react";

export default function SignInSide(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  const handleChange = (e) => setData(e.target.value);
  return (
    <form>
      <label>
        User Name:
        <input type="text" value={data} onChange={handleChange} />
      </label>
      <button type="button" onClick={() => props.onChangeUsername(data)}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Application View**

[image]

Check the `console logs` as shown in the application view to identify whether username is updated in main component.